# Multiple arguments for !somearray.contains

Tags: java, contains

Is it possible to have multiple arguments for a `.contains`?  I am searching an `array` to ensure that each `string` contains one of several characters.  I've hunted all over the web, but found nothing useful.

```
        for(String s : fileContents) {
            if(!s.contains(syntax1) && !s.contains(syntax2)) {
                found.add(s);
                }
            }           

        for (String s : found) {
            System.out.println(s);      // print array to cmd
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Note:  Syntax errors found.");
            }
```

How can I do this with multiple arguments?  I've also tried a bunch of `||`s on their own, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Also, for the second case, are you sure it isn't because you're getting bitten by operator precedence issues?

Comment: What is the type of `syntax1`?

Comment: @Vash syntax* are strings.  I've added the code.

Comment: Whay do you concatenate syntax1 with "" ?

Comment: @dennis, No, I'm not.  I'm a beginner at this, and I couldn't find much on making multiple `!somearray.contains`  What issues jump out at you?

Comment: @Vash Because I'm searching for a `string` within a `string` in an `array` and, I've been told that's the best way to do it.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: Who told you that's the best way to do it?!

Comment: @roippi I think that is what I want.

Comment: Wait, hold on. Two things. 1) Why are you using `contains` and not `indexOf(String str)` and 2) are you trying to see if the string contains at least one of multiple substrings, or if it contains *none* of the substrings?

Comment: @InDeep, Yes. That operation do not have sense.

Comment: @Dennis Judging my that '?!' I shouldn't name any names.  Please do to tell me all about how it should really be done.  I'll take any little tidbits I can get.

Comment: There are lots of minor weird stuff in your code. You should find some examples of similar stuff online to see how it's done in general.

Comment: @DennisMeng, The contains is valid till he do not look for presence not for position.

Comment: @InDeep, as far as trying to see whether or not a string contains a separate string, concatenating `""` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Vash Ah wait, when I was reading the docs I didn't realize `CharSequence` was an interface implemented by `String`, I thought it was something completely different. Ignore me :)

Comment: @dennis "are you trying to see if the string contains at least one of multiple substrings, or if it contains none of the substrings?"  Ultimately I want to have all the lines in an `array` that do not contain one of 4 characters (`strings`) somewhere in them.  So none of the substrings.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't you be using `&&` instead of `||`? You want it to not contain a substring *and* not contain some other substring and so on.

Comment: @vash You're right about not needing to concatenate the `string` with "".  Is it possible that that's for finding a `char` in a string?

Comment: @InDeep Nope. To do that, you could just pass a character to `indexOf()` and check against `-1`.

Comment: @InDeep, It might be used as that but is not proper way to check. If you check the char you use the `indexOf` and check the result is not equal to -1. Witch is returned if char was not found.

Comment: @vash Does it matter that I'm searching an `arraylist` and loading returned `strings` into another?  Originally this was intended to be a search 'n replace function.

Comment: It does. What you must know what when you concatenate a one string to another you create third one. String have very big impact on performance. If you change something in a loop then StringBuilder class is more adapt for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't have multiple arguments, but the `||` should work.

`!s.contains(syntax1+"") || !s.contains(syntax2+"")` means `s` doesn't contain `syntax1` or it doesn't contain `syntax2`.

This is just a guess but you might want `s` contains either of the two:

```
s.contains(syntax1+"") || s.contains(syntax2+"")
```

or maybe `s` contains both:

```
s.contains(syntax1+"") && s.contains(syntax2+"")
```

or maybe `s` contains neither of the two:

```
!s.contains(syntax1+"") && !s.contains(syntax2+"")
```

If syntax1 and syntax2 are already strings, you don't need the `+""`'s.

I believe `s.contains("")` should always return true, so you can remove it.

Comment: AHA!  Now I see what Vash is saying about the operations.  I'm pretty sure I want "!s.contains(syntax1+"") && !s.contains(syntax2+"")"  Let me go test it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you described can be done with a **[regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)**.

In regular expression, **the operator `|`** marks you need to match one of several choices.

For example, the regex `(a|b)` means a or b.

The regex `".*(a|b).*"` means a string that contains a or b, and other then that - all is OK (it assumes one line string, but that can be dealt with easily as well if needed).

Code example:

```
    String s = "abc";
    System.out.println(s.matches(".*(a|d).*"));
    s = "abcd";
    System.out.println(s.matches(".*(a|d).*"));
    s = "fgh";
    System.out.println(s.matches(".*(a|d).*"));
```

---

Regular Exprsssions is a powerful tool that I recommend learning. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as multiple contains.

if you require to validate that a list of string is included in some other string you must iterate through them all and check.

```
public static boolean containsAll(String input, String... items) {

    if(input == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must not be null"); // We validate the input


    if(input.length() == 0) {
        return items.length == 0; // if empty contains nothing then true, else false
    }

    boolean result = true;

    for(String item : items) {
        result = result && input.contains(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `if(input.length() == 0)` check is necessary. It will return the same without it.